# Google analytics - Add analytics label value

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 types of products : productA and productB.

Whenever products are getting sold I am sending events (product name with price) to GA as:

event-category - productA/productB

event-action - product sold

event-label - 20

I need to create a chart where I can see sum of cost of productA and productB separately.
Something like this :

**EventCategory**     **Event Label**

productA              100

productB              400

Comment: Are the values Integers? (> 0, no decimals)

Comment: @Tico they are decimals

Comment: @Tico : It doesn't matter whether it's decimal or integer. I need sum.

Comment: If they were Integers, you could use Event Value. You will probably need GTM for that. Via dataLayer or getting via JS

Comment: @Tico : Requirement changed and it's integer now. Event Value helped. Thanks!!!

Comment: Lucky you, I had to deal with it and it sucks! Event Value should accept decimals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sum those values ​​in Analytics because the label is a **dimension**, so it's interpreted as a **string**.

For what you need you must use the **event value** or a **custom metric** associated with the event. In this way the values ​​become summable.

In your case you can only **export the data**, i.e. to an Excel, and perform calculations outside of Analytics.

Comment: Thanks Michele!!!
I was about thinking to go for custom metrics but event value helped.